# Can we shorten/remove the question title length requirement?

Tags: discussion

Currently, the JSE requires its question titles be at least 15 characters long. However, this 15-character requirement was set for English, in which a word is easily 4-10 letters long, and any question in under 15 characters can be safely assumed to be too brief. In Japanese, however, with Kanji, the information density is much higher, and a complete question can be well under 15 characters.

My personal experience: I recently asked a question about the word 雛たち in Japanese. I wanted to make the title:

> 雛たちとは？ [6 chars] OR 雛たちとは何でしょうか？ [12 chars]

Had I asked in English, the lengths would be:

> What does 雛たち mean? [19 chars]

I had to change the question to 雛たちとは何の意味でしょうか？ to pass the 15-char limit.

In short, I feel the 15-char limit is designed to work with English, which has a lower information density than Japanese. Having to expand my question to fit the 15-char requirement felt extra and unnecessary. Should we lower the 15-char limit, or just have it removed?

Comment: Just want to let the community knows that technically it's possible to change the length limit, as shown on [Japanese SO with 8 characters](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3085/2767).

Answer (score 1):

In principle I agree that titles entirely in Japanese should have a lower character limit, however there may be some other issues since majority of the questions appear to be written in English.

One possible problem is that it lowers the barrier to low quality questions. We frequently receive (poorly titled) translation or transcription requests. But one may argue that a higher length limit doesn't do much to improve the quality of such questions anyway.  I.e. a user may just change the title from "translate" to "please translate" just to get around the length filter.

Now it seems (as of writing this post) there are no strong opinions either way. **If there is sufficient community support in changing the minimum length, we'll escalate to the community team to implement the changes.**

A quick reminder that votes in Meta may not convey the same information as votes normally do on the main site. On Meta, it is difficult to distinguish between an upvote for indicating that the issue is worth discussing, and an upvote that indicates agreement with the proposition in the post. (For example, my upvote on the question post indicates that I feel that this issue is worth discussing, but it may or may not indicate my support for the changes)

For this reason I will state clearly the use for upvotes on **this** answer post.

**Upvote this post if you are in agreement with decreasing the minimum character limit**

**Downvote this post if you do not agree with decreasing the minimum character limit**